# Problem Re-baking from Voxel model to generic model

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-baking, baking

I made a voxel model from Magika voxel and I tried to remake the model because the way Magika voxel exporting is simply shrunk uv maps to small pieces of color boxes texture. This makes hard to bake extra effects such as Ambient Occlusion, shadows, ETC.

[image: Original Model]

So I found the solution on YouTube(https://youtu.be/5MY3rsq5JGw) and it quite worked well until I baked more complex model.

I copied mesh and made new material and uvmap. After I bake the new model,[image] it seems the blender bakes some faces reflective.

[image: Baked Model]
This is the work space when I baked
[image]